# Function SetAppDir already exists, add ! to replace it - django vim

Tags: django, vim

I follow the instruction on django site to add the following to my vimrc file but when I try to save the file I get an error:

```
Function SetAppDir already exists, add ! to replace it
```

Tried to add ! to SetAppDir()!, or call! SetAppDir but still no luck.

[Here is the code from django site:](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/UsingVimWithDjango)

```
let g:last_relative_dir = ''
nnoremap \1 :call RelatedFile ("models.py")<cr>
nnoremap \2 :call RelatedFile ("views.py")<cr>
nnoremap \3 :call RelatedFile ("urls.py")<cr>
nnoremap \4 :call RelatedFile ("admin.py")<cr>
nnoremap \5 :call RelatedFile ("tests.py")<cr>
nnoremap \6 :call RelatedFile ( "templates/" )<cr>
nnoremap \7 :call RelatedFile ( "templatetags/" )<cr>
nnoremap \8 :call RelatedFile ( "management/" )<cr>
nnoremap \0 :e settings.py<cr>
nnoremap \9 :e urls.py<cr>

fun! RelatedFile(file)
    #This is to check that the directory looks djangoish
    if filereadable(expand("%:h"). '/models.py') || isdirectory(expand("%:h") . "/templatetags/")
        exec "edit %:h/" . a:file
        let g:last_relative_dir = expand("%:h") . '/'
        return ''
    endif
    if g:last_relative_dir != ''
        exec "edit " . g:last_relative_dir . a:file
        return ''
    endif
    echo "Cant determine where relative file is : " . a:file
    return ''
endfun

fun SetAppDir()
    if filereadable(expand("%:h"). '/models.py') || isdirectory(expand("%:h") . "/templatetags/")
        let g:last_relative_dir = expand("%:h") . '/'
        return ''
    endif
endfun
autocmd BufEnter *.py call SetAppDir()
```

Comment: Notice the `fun!` before the definition of `RelatedFile`?  Do the same for `SetAppDir`.  As for why you're getting this error I'm not sure.  The function should only be defined once, unless you are repeatedly sourcing this file.

Comment: Heehaaa, worked. django needs to correct thier site. Many thanks.

Comment: The wiki is not actively maintained by anyone, and there's a lot of outdated information. You can edit the page yourself, but personally I mostly ignore its existence and get my information from more reliable sources (such as the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/) or SO).

Comment: I agree, I tried a few of the code there and it doesn't seem to work properly. I thought that is the part of the official doc, but according to you it is not. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @randy-morris for his tip.

Had to modify the code and add ! just after fun and before SetAppDir()

```
fun! SetAppDir()
if filereadable(expand("%:h"). '/models.py') || isdirectory(expand("%:h") . "/templatetags/")
    let g:last_relative_dir = expand("%:h") . '/'
    return ''
endif
```

endfun
autocmd BufEnter *.py call SetAppDir()